# Why come output as 9 when I call to display method using getModifiers() method in (Reflection of Java Methods)?

Tags: java, reflection, access-modifiers

This is `Dog` class and it includes `display` and `makesound` methods

```
 class Dog {
        // methods of the class
        public static void display() {
            System.out.println("I am a dog.");
        }    
        private void makeSound() {
            System.out.println("Bark Bark");
    }
    }
```

This is main class.

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {       
            // create an object of Dog
            Dog d1 = new Dog();

            // create an object of Class
            // using getClass()
            Class obj = d1.getClass();

            // using object of Class to
            // get all the declared methods of Dog
            Method[] methods = obj.getDeclaredMethods();

            // create an object of the Method class
            for (Method m : methods) {
                // get the access modifier of methods
                int modifier = m.getModifiers();
                System.out.println("Modifires " +  modifier);
            }
        }
   
        }
    }
}
```

When I call the make sound method using `getModifiers` method the output is  2 but the display method gets output as 9. Why is that? I thought display method has 3 access modifires. But `Modifier.toString(modifier)` shows output as public and static for `display` method.

Comment: Why do you assume `getModifiers()` returns the _count_ of modifiers? Have you checked the documentation for that method? What it _actually_ does?

Comment: That's not the number of modifiers for the method. That is a constant that should be decoded using the methods of the [`Modifier`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Modifier.html) class

Answer (score 3):

The `int` value returned by [`Method.getModifiers()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getModifiers--) is actually a [bit field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field). It allows expressing multiple integer values (often called flags) as a single integer by performing a bitwise OR (`|`) operation.

The bit flag values for the various modifiers are documented in the [`Modifier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Modifier.html) class. These are the values:

| Modifier | Value |
| --- | --- |
| `abstract` | 1024 |
| `final` | 16 |
| `interface` | 512 |
| `native` | 256 |
| `private` | 2 |
| `protected` | 4 |
| `public` | 1 |
| `static` | 8 |
| `strict` | 2048 |
| `synchronized` | 32 |
| `transient` | 128 |
| `volatile` | 64 |

(Note that for your specific example, `public static` corresponds to `1 | 8`, which equals `9`.)

You can call [`Modifier.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Modifier.html#toString-int-) to get a text representation, or use one of the utility methods to check whether a certain modifier is present.